# Looking for different tags in two XML files when the content is different

Tags: xml, diff

From time to time I translate some Android apps: the developer sends me an XML file, e.g.

```
<string name="foo">Foo</string>
<string name="baz">Baz</string>
```

and I send him back an XML file where the content of each element has been translated, e.g.

```
<string name="foo">Translated foo</string>
<string name="baz">Translated baz</string>
```

The problem arises when the developer adds some new text element and sends me a new file to be translated, e.g.

```
<string name="foo">Foo</string>
<string name="bar">Bar</string>
<string name="baz">Baz</string>
```

**Question:** How can I compare this to my previous translated file looking only for the tags with new attributes or, better still, is there a simple(ish) way to *merge* the two files, possibly adding a marker at the beginning of the new lines to be translated?

Given the previous example, this would mean generating a file like

```
<string name="foo">Translated foo</string>
<!-- new --><string name="bar">Bar</string>
<string name="baz">Translated baz</string>
```

Comment: Tell the developer to either send you new versions that are based on the already translated versions you supplied, or mark the differences before they send it to you. Having you repeatedly search through old tags like this (after already providing translations and updated files) is asinine, since the dev. knows his changes better than anyone. /opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't find any pre-existing solution I decided to write a small Python script myself which so far seems to do the job:

```py
"""Usage: merge_strings.py [-m <mrk>] [-o <file> [-i]] <old_xml> <new_xml>

Substitutes the content of any 'string' tag from <new_xml> with the
content of a 'string' tag from <old_xml> with the same 'name' attribute,
if present, otherwise prepends it with <mrk>.
By default the result is printed to stdout.

Note: This program assumes that no two 'string' tags in the same file
have the same 'name' attribute. Furthermore, 'string' tags with names
unique to <old_xml> are ignored.

Options:
    -h --help                 Show this screen.
    -m <mrk> --marker <mrk>   Marker for new strings [default: ***new***].
    -o <file>                 Print to <file> instead.
    -i --interactive          Check before overwriting <file>.
"""

from os.path import isfile
from sys import exit

from docopt import docopt
import lxml.etree as etree


def merge_strings(old, new, marker):
    """
    Merge in place synonymous strings from 'old' into 'new'.
    Ignores strings unique to 'old' and prepends strings unique to
    'new' with 'marker'.
    """
    for s in new.iterfind('//string'):
        name = s.attrib['name']
        t = old.find("//string[@name='" + name + "']")

        if t is not None:
            s.text = t.text
        else:
            s.text = marker + s.text

def check_overwrite(path):
    """
    Check if we want to overwrite 'path' and exit if not.
    Defaults to no.
    """
    print("About to overwrite:", path)
    choice = input("Continue? [y/N]")

    if choice.lower() != 'y':
        exit(0)

def print_to_file(tree, path, interactive=False):
    if interactive and isfile(path):
        check_overwrite(path)

    with open(path, mode='wb') as f:
        tree.write(f, pretty_print=True,
                      encoding='utf-8',
                      xml_declaration=True)

def print_to_stdout(tree):
    print(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True,
                               encoding='utf-8',
                               xml_declaration=True).decode('utf-8'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = docopt(__doc__)

    old_tree = etree.parse(args['<old_xml>'])
    new_tree = etree.parse(args['<new_xml>'])

    merge_strings(old_tree, new_tree, args['--marker'])

    if args['-o']:
        print_to_file(new_tree, args['-o'], args['--interactive'])
    else:
        print_to_stdout(new_tree)
```

Here is the obligatory example output:

```
$cat tests/old.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="foo">Translated foo</string>
  <string name="baz">Translated baz</string>
</resources>

$cat tests/new.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="foo">Foo</string>
  <string name="bar">Bar</string>
  <string name="baz">Baz</string>
</resources>

$python merge_strings.py old.xml new.xml                                                   
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<resources>
  <string name="foo">Translated foo</string>
  <string name="bar">***new***Bar</string>
  <string name="baz">Translated baz</string>
</resources>
```

**Remark:** I am relatively new to Python and completely new to XML, so any comments on how to improve the above code would be greatly appreciated.